# tI'm trying to make an encryption program for school, but I'm having trouble actually replacing the alphanumerics with my special characters

Tags: python

I've tried multiple methods with different imports but they all seem to have some sort of problem when they're implemented in my code.
Here is the current version:

```
#Variables
passcode= 24601
confirm= 0
msg= 0
x=0

#Functions
def confirm_choice():
    answer = ""
    while answer not in ["y", "n"]:
        answer = input("Is this the message you want encrypted? Y/N: ").lower()
    return answer == "y"

def encrypt():
  x= msg.replace("A", "‡")
  x= msg.replace("B", "֎")
  x= msg.replace("C", "Ѫ")
  x= msg.replace("D", "^")
  x= msg.replace("E", "҈")
  x= msg.replace("F", "₩")
  x= msg.replace("G", "Д")
  x= msg.replace("H", "҂")
  x= msg.replace("I", "*")
  x= msg.replace("J", "Ͱ")
  x= msg.replace("K", "֍")
  x= msg.replace("L", "҉")
  x= msg.replace("M", "!")
  x= msg.replace("N", "Ӕ")
  x= msg.replace("O", "჻")
  x= msg.replace("P", "ʘ")
  x= msg.replace("Q", "¶")
  x= msg.replace("R", "%")
  x= msg.replace("S", "Θ")
  x= msg.replace("T", "@")
  x= msg.replace("U", "Δ")
  x= msg.replace("V", "$")
  x= msg.replace("W", "‽")
  x= msg.replace("X", "¥")
  x= msg.replace("Y", "˧")
  x= msg.replace("Z", "~")
  x= msg.replace("1", "Փ")
  x= msg.replace("2", "§")
  x= msg.replace("3", "₿")
  x= msg.replace("4", "Ω")
  x= msg.replace("5", "©")
  x= msg.replace("6", "&")
  x= msg.replace("7", "£")
  x= msg.replace("8", "◊")
  x= msg.replace("9", "€")
  x= msg.replace("0", "#")
  print(x)

#Passcode guarantees only authorised users can use and access encryption key
code= int(input("Enter the passcode: " ))
if passcode == code:
  print("Access Granted.")
else:
  print("Incorrect Passcode. Access Denied")
  quit

#Takes input for encryption
msg= input("What message do you wish to send, comrade? Make sure it is in all capitals. \n")

confirm_choice()

encrypt()
```

*Notes*

I am coding in replit.com, but I'm not sure if that can cause this type of issue.

Confirm Choice and Passcode functions are for "Program Complexity" on the rubric.

Comment: So, what is the problem?

Comment: pass the msg as an argument to the encrypt function, and in encrypt function add argument x

Comment: "they all seem to have some sort of problem when they're implemented in my code" We can only help you with problems that you actually describe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`str.translate` + `str.maketrans` is much more efficient than 36 replaces in a row.

```
def encrypt():
    x = msg.translate(str.maketrans({'A': '‡', 'B': '֎', 'C': 'Ѫ', 'D': '^', 'E': '҈', 'F': '₩', 'G': 'Д', 'H': '҂', 'I': '*', 'J': 'Ͱ', 'K': '֍', 'L': '҉', 'M': '!', 'N': 'Ӕ', 'O': '჻', 'P': 'ʘ', 'Q': '¶', 'R': '%', 'S': 'Θ', 'T': '@', 'U': 'Δ', 'V': '$', 'W': '‽', 'X': '¥', 'Y': '˧', 'Z': '~', '1': 'Փ', '2': '§', '3': '₿', '4': 'Ω', '5': '©', '6': '&', 
'7': '£', '8': '◊', '9': '€', '0': '#'}))
    print(x)
```

Comment: I agree that this is more practical.

Answer (score 1):

You're overwriting `x` every time you do a new `msg.replace`, so only the last replace will take effect. Also, `quit()` is a built-in *function*. This should work.

```py
# Variables
passcode = 24601
confirm = 0
msg = 0
x = 0

# Functions


def confirm_choice():
    answer = ""
    while answer not in ["y", "n"]:
        answer = input("Is this the message you want encrypted? Y/N: ").lower()
    return answer == "y"


def encrypt(msg: str):
    x = msg.replace("A", "‡")
    x = x.replace("B", "֎")
    x = x.replace("C", "Ѫ")
    x = x.replace("D", "^")
    x = x.replace("E", "҈")
    x = x.replace("F", "₩")
    x = x.replace("G", "Д")
    x = x.replace("H", "҂")
    x = x.replace("I", "*")
    x = x.replace("J", "Ͱ")
    x = x.replace("K", "֍")
    x = x.replace("L", "҉")
    x = x.replace("M", "!")
    x = x.replace("N", "Ӕ")
    x = x.replace("O", "჻")
    x = x.replace("P", "ʘ")
    x = x.replace("Q", "¶")
    x = x.replace("R", "%")
    x = x.replace("S", "Θ")
    x = x.replace("T", "@")
    x = x.replace("U", "Δ")
    x = x.replace("V", "$")
    x = x.replace("W", "‽")
    x = x.replace("X", "¥")
    x = x.replace("Y", "˧")
    x = x.replace("Z", "~")
    x = x.replace("1", "Փ")
    x = x.replace("2", "§")
    x = x.replace("3", "₿")
    x = x.replace("4", "Ω")
    x = x.replace("5", "©")
    x = x.replace("6", "&")
    x = x.replace("7", "£")
    x = x.replace("8", "◊")
    x = x.replace("9", "€")
    x = x.replace("0", "#")
    return x


# Passcode guarantees only authorised users can use and access encryption key
code = int(input("Enter the passcode: "))
if passcode == code:
    print("Access Granted.")
else:
    print("Incorrect Passcode. Access Denied")
    quit()

# Takes input for encryption
msg = input(
    "What message do you wish to send, comrade? Make sure it is in all capitals. \n")

if confirm_choice():
    print(encrypt(msg))
else:
    print(msg)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try a dictionary:

```
dct = {'A': '‡', 'B': '֎', 'C': 'Ѫ', 'D': '^', 'E': '҈', 'F': '₩', 'G': 'Д', 'H': '҂', 'I': '*', 'J': 'Ͱ', 'K': '֍', 'L': '҉', 'M': '!', 'N': 'Ӕ', 'O': '჻', 'P': 'ʘ', 'Q': '¶', 'R': '%', 'S': 'Θ', 'T': '@', 'U': 'Δ', 'V': '$', 'W': '‽', 'X': '¥', 'Y': '˧', 'Z': '~', '1': 'Փ', '2': '§', '3': '₿', '4': 'Ω', '5': '©', '6': '&', '7': '£', '8': '◊', '9': '€', '0': '#'}

word = input(">>> ")

for k in dct:
    word = word.replace(k, dct[k])
    
print(word)
```